# in python unittest, unable to run a specific case when cases are generated automatically

Tags: python, python-unittest

I use below method to generate cases automatically in python unittest.

```
import unittest
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def check(self, i):
        self.assertNotEquals(0, i)

for i in [0, 1, 2]:
    def ch(i):
        return lambda self: self.check(i)
    setattr(Tests, "test_%d" % i, ch(i))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

It works well when "python test.py" to run all cases together.
But fails to run a specific case, like "python test.py Tests.test_0"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 128, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 109, in loadTestsFromName
    return self.suiteClass([parent(obj.__name__)])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 191, in __init__
    (self.__class__, methodName))
ValueError: no such test method in <class '__main__.Tests'>: <lambda>
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Fix the indentation please, it's quite confusing

Comment: @msvalkon -- I think the indentation is as the OP wants it.  I believe OP is trying to monkey-patch methods onto the Test class after the Test class is created...

Comment: @msvalkon, I want to use monkey-patch way to generate method test_0, test_1, test_2 in Test class automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears (from the error message) and from perusing the source of `unittest`, that the test runner gets a reference to the method and then uses the method's `__name__` attribute to figure out which method to run.  This is a bit silly (after all, we already picked up a reference to the method!), but it does have some benefits in terms of code simplicity.  The quick fix is to make sure that you set the name on your lambda functions as well:

```
import unittest
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def check(self, i):
        self.assertNotEquals(0, i)

for i in [0, 1, 2]:
    def ch(i):
        return lambda self: self.check(i)
    f = ch(i)
    name = "test_%d" % i
    f.__name__ = name
    setattr(Tests, name, f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Now everything works as it should:

```
mgilson$ python test.py Tests.test_0
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_0 (__main__.Tests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <lambda>
    return lambda self: self.check(i)
  File "test.py", line 5, in check
    self.assertNotEquals(0, i)
AssertionError: 0 == 0

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

and:

```
mgilson$ python test.py Tests.test_1
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

---

Note that it appears this this was a bug which was fixed.  In the [current HEAD](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/486c1a81ee32/Lib/unittest/loader.py#l123), we can see that the name is parsed from the string as opposed to in the [version which I have](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/fe18f16dc2a6/Lib/unittest/loader.py#l122) (and apparently you do to) where the name is picked up from the object (function) to be run.

Comment: Oh, yes, this issue should have been fixed in the newer version.